# Irreducible $F$-representations of finite abelian groups, for finite field $F$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

$A$ is a finite abelian group, $F$ is a finite field and $F[A]$ is the group algebra of $A$ over $F$.

Let $V$ be an irreducible finite-dimensional $F[A]$-module. Let $\rho : F[A] \rightarrow GL(V)$ be the corresponding representation.

I think I have a proof that $\rho(A)$ must be cyclic, and I'd like to know if the proof is valid. My argument is as follows:

**Proof:**

Since $V$ is irreducible, we must have by Schur's Lemma that $\text{Hom}_{F[A]}(V,V)$ (the ring of $F[A]$-module-homomorphisms from $V$ into $V$) is a division algebra.

Since $A$ is abelian, $F[A]$ is a commutative ring, so $\rho(F[A])\subseteq\text{Hom}_{F[A]}(V,V)$.

This means that $\rho(F[A])$ is a finite commutative division ring; that is to say, it is a finite field! In particular, its multiplicative group of units $\rho(F[A])^\times$ is cyclic. Since $\rho(A)$ is a subgroup of $\rho(F[A])^\times$, it follows that $\rho(A)$ is cyclic. $\blacksquare$

I'd like to know if I'm deluding myself.

Comment: A subring/subalgebra of a division ring does not have to be division. But it is an integral domain, and finite integral domain is a field. Yeah, it looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks! I have a regrettable tendency to guess that whatever is convenient is probably true.